# Grub help, deleting partition without deleting grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub, grub2

I have a triple boot windows 7, ubuntu 10.10, ubuntu 11.10 and i want to delete the partitiion containing 11.10 but that's where my grub is located I believe.  Because it updated to grub 1.99 when I downloaded installed 11.10.  How can I change this so that even after the partition is deleted I can use grub.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to boot from exact Ubuntu version, you can run grub-install with --root-directory option (if your required partition is mounted to /mnt):

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

It's a good idea to have a separate /boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Boot from Ubuntu 10.10 ( which u don't want to delete ), Open terminal and type command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` . And then `sudo reboot` . If now grub of Ubuntu 10.10 is there, then you can safely delete partitions of 11.10 and remove the entry of 11.10 from /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live cd like on of your ubuntu install cds and open a Terminal. Now mount one of your ubuntu partitions. Assuming /dev/sda7 is your ubuntu 11.10 partition you can accomplish this by issuing the following command as root user:

```
sudo -s
mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
```

Now you can use **chroot** to change in the mounted operating system:

```
chroot /mnt
```

Now it should be easy to use grub-install:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Now change to */etc/grub.d/* where you should find a script  called *30-os-prober*. This script will scan the hard disks for other operating systems and add them to the boot menu. Therefor as root you should execute this script:

```
sudo /etc/grub.d/30-os-prober
```

And as final step update your grub.

```
update-grub
```

Also i found [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html) helpful site.